# the group by in mysql5.7

Tags: mysql

I find the same sql run in mysql5.7 and mysql5.5 but the result is different.

the sql like this:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM (SELECT t1.* FROM t_user t1 ORDER BY t1.id desc) AS t2 GROUP BY t2.type;
```

The result in mysql5.7:
[image: the result in mysql5.7]

The result in mysql5.5:
[image: the result in mysql5.5]

the sql script like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_user`;
CREATE TABLE `t_user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_delete` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('1', 'James', '0594-5397864', '0', '3', '2016-01-30 19:01:09', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('2', 'Hayes', '0594-5392419', '1', '4', '2015-12-24 11:12:27', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('3', 'Diana', '0594-5393520', '1', '5', '2016-03-21 13:03:50', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('4', 'Rajah', '0594-5399812', '1', '4', '2015-11-26 02:11:35', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('5', 'Daria', '0594-5397571', '0', '4', '2016-01-18 11:01:11', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('6', 'Lee', '0594-5394539', '1', '1', '2015-10-23 08:10:23', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('7', 'Cameran', '0594-5392867', '0', '4', '2016-11-16 12:11:08', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('8', 'Wylie', '0594-5395349', '0', '5', '2017-07-06 04:07:27', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('9', 'Bertha', '0594-5395287', '1', '1', '2017-02-08 12:02:45', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('10', 'Fletcher', '0594-5399246', '0', '4', '2015-09-03 20:09:33', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('11', 'Conan', '0594-5391546', '1', '5', '2017-05-15 09:05:23', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('12', 'Raymond', '0594-5399666', '0', '3', '2015-10-20 05:10:05', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('13', 'Noel', '0594-5397392', '1', '4', '2017-05-26 03:05:56', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('14', 'Miriam', '0594-5399081', '0', '2', '2016-05-21 02:05:09', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('15', 'Maya', '0594-5397242', '0', '3', '2016-10-24 02:10:50', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('16', 'Winifred', '0594-5395142', '1', '1', '2017-03-15 02:03:43', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('17', 'Elaine', '0594-5398478', '1', '3', '2017-03-08 15:03:03', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('18', 'Robert', '0594-5397830', '0', '5', '2016-02-10 22:02:06', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('19', 'Patrick', '0594-5396516', '0', '4', '2015-09-10 07:09:51', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('20', 'Darrel', '0594-5397417', '0', '1', '2016-03-11 11:03:36', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('21', 'Salvador', '0594-5399732', '1', '3', '2016-01-01 15:01:21', '0');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('22', 'Brandon', '0594-5396204', '1', '4', '2016-05-12 06:05:40', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('23', 'Dorothy', '0594-5396783', '0', '1', '2016-12-12 10:12:59', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('24', 'Kevyn', '0594-5398240', '0', '2', '2016-02-07 04:02:14', '1');
INSERT INTO `t_user` VALUES ('25', 'Brody', '0594-5398774', '1', '1', '2016-12-11 20:12:36', '0');
```

what cause this different...  my English is poor,LOL...

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense. Why to use subquery? You an directly use `SELECT t1.* FROM t_user t1 ORDER BY t1.id desc GROUP BY t1.type`

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, MySQL is free to choose whichever result it likes on non-aggregated columns. In this instance, two different versions of MySQL choose two different results. My guess is that one prioritises the the ordering implicit in the GROUP BY, while the other prioritises the ordering explicit in the subquery. Note that kaushik karan's suggestion is equally non-deterministic and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is too liberal when it comes to data integrity and its default settings often allow you to accomplish data loss without a complaint (see reference for [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)). For instance, it allows incomplete GROUP BY clauses like yours and just picks an arbitrary (not even random) result.

You need to rewrite your query so all columns involved fit into one category:

- Be part of an aggregate expression in the SELECT clause:

  ```
  SELECT MAX(foo) AS maximum_foo
  ```
- Be part of the GROUP BY clause:

  ```
  SELECT foo
  ...
  GROUP BY foo
  ```

This way you are being specific enough so the result-set is deterministic. Your current code is basically: "Give me one user of each type"—but you don't specify any criteria to pick users. Other DBMSs (Oracle, SQL Server) will complaint: "You didn't say how to choose users". MySQL will merely pick an arbitrary user (but not even a random user, because randomness would imply that chosen users follow a rule, which is not the case). The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is just a way to make MySQL behave like other engines.

You can also get rid of your subquery, it really serves no purpose.

Comment: thx for your replay，I just change the sql like this：select t1.* from t_user t1 where t1.id in (select max(t2.id) from t_user t2 GROUP BY t2.type);    it will get the same result。

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my answer. What I mean is that your query triggers different results because it doesn't ask for a deterministic result set. It's like "I want fish as main course", you may get salmon or cob. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No order on outer SELECT causes the difference. However what do you want to achieve? Take only one (which one) from each group (type) or what?

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_user
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t_user GROUP BY type)
ORDER BY type
```

SQL fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f47d/3)

Comment: I just want get the max id record in each group（group by type）。

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: nice.the result thath is i want.  but do you konw why the quesition's sql cause the different result. because of  the sql_mode ?

Comment: If this is answer to your question confim it as accepted answer. In your query you did not defined which one from group so MySQL can pick an arbitrary one as @Álvaro González explained.